# R programming: Level of allowed recursion depth differs when calling a local helper function

Tags: r, recursion

this is a purely academic question:
I have recently been working with languages that use tail recursion optimization. For practice I wrote two recursive implementations of  sum functions in R, one of them being tail recursive. I quickly realized there is no tail recursion optimization in R. I can live with that.
However, I also noticed a different level of allowed depth when using the local helper function for the tail recursion.

Here is the code:

```
## Recursive
sum <- function (i, end, fun){
  if (i>=end) 0
  else fun(i) + sum(i+1, end, fun)
}


## Tail recursive

sum_tail <- function (i, end, fun){
  sum_helper<- function(i, acc){
    if (i>=end) acc
    else sum_helper(i+1, acc+fun(i))
  }

  sum_helper(i, 0)
}




## Simple example

harmonic <- function(k){
  return(1/(k))
}


print(sum(1, 1200, harmonic)) # <- This works fine, but is close to the limit
# print(sum_tail(1, 1200, harmonic)) <- This will crash
print(sum_tail(1, 996, harmonic)) # <- This is the deepest allowed
```

I am fairly intrigued. Can someone explain this behavior or point me towards a document explaining how the allowed recursion depth is calculated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of R's internal implementation of the call stack, but it's pretty obvious from here that there is a maximum stack depth. (Many languages have this for various reasons, mostly related to memory and detecting infinite recursion.) You can set it with `options()`, and the default setting seems to depends on the platform -- on my machine, I can do `print(sum_tail(1, 996, harmonic))` without difficulty.

Sidebar: you really shouldn't name your naive implementation `sum()` because you wind up shadowing a builtin. I know you're just playing with recursion here, but you should also generally avoid doing your own implementation of `sum()` -- it's not provided just as a convenience function but also because it's non trivial to implement a numerically correct version of `sum()` with floating point.

In your naive implementation, the call to `fun()` returns before the recursive call -- this means that each recursive call increases the depth of the call stack by exactly 1. In the other case, you've got an additional function call that's waiting to be evaluated. For more details, you should look into how R handles closures and how lazy / eager evaluation in R is handled. If I recall correctly, R uses environments (roughly, R's notion of scope, and deeply related to closures) to wrap arguments in certain situations and delay their evaluation, thus effectively using lazy evaluation. There's a lot of information on R internals available online, see here for a quick overview of [argument evaluation](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#Argument-evaluation). I'm not sure how accurate I am on the details, but it seems that the arguments to the tail-call are themselves getting placed on the call stack, thus increasing the depth of the call-stack by more than 1.

Sidebar the Second: I don't recall well enough how R implements this, and I know placing helper functions in the body is common practice, but placing a helper function definition in the recursive call *could* lead to each recursive call defining the helper function anew. This could interact in various ways with the way environments and closures are handled, but I'm not sure.

The functions [`traceback()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/traceback.html) and [`trace()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/trace.html) could be useful in exploring the call behavior if you're curious about more of the details.

Comment: Perfect. It's due to the Lazy Evaluation. If I force(acc), then both versions achieve equal depth. I also checked with the debugger: R first adds all recursive calls of the helper to the stack and then starts adding the call to fun() - although R exits fun() immediately after evaluation 1/k, it seams to make the difference.
So I am not entirely sure about the details, but I understand the problem a lot better now ;)